# How can I determine the length of received bytes of UsbRequest.queue(..) method?

Tags: android, usb, communication, bytebuffer

I have troubles with UsbRequest class in Android 3.1.

This is my code:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
request.initialize(mConnection, mEndpointIn);
request.queue(buffer, 4096);

if (mConnection.requestWait() == request) {
   byte[] data = buffer.array();
}
```

The size of array `data` is 4096, but the length of really received bytes is much more smaller.

How can i determine the size of really received bytes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This was a [bug in Android](http://b.android.com/28023).  On afflicted versions, there's no workaround, because the implementation simply doesn't pass the length up.

It was [fixed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/a3665ba95d806fcb6780d29d49bd0f1032e8bc86) in JB-MR1 (API level 17 onwards).

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the current asynchronous USB API has no way to return the read size. 2 "workarounds" use synchronous transfers as there you receive the number of bytes read/written or maybe the protocol you are implementing sends you the number of bytes you'll receive. E.g. i'm currently implementing something where every higher-level packet i receive has the number of bytes in the first 4 bytes of the packet. Based on this number i know if i have to do multiple reads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.queue(buffer, bufferLength);`. This should solve your problem. Now, you should refer android documentation, it's well documented and helpful.

Comment: The link is broken and @Slava is already using that method anyway

Comment: I had answered this question back in Oct 31 '12, back then this link was working fine and to the best of my knowledge I answered it when API 16 was in effect. Btw, it's a blocking queue it'll wait till bufferLength amount is available.

Comment: You should fix your link

Answer (score 0):

I believe `buffer.limit()` should return the number of received bytes. Does that work?

Comment: Hello, No. In my case the limit is 4096. It is the limit of buffer.

Comment: Ah. Weird. Try `buffer.position()`? My understanding was that `limit` was not the same as `capacity`, but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: No. Position is `0`.
Here all vars:
 _elementSizeShift=0, capacity=4096,effectiveDirectAddress=0, limit = 4096, mark = -1, offset=0, position =0